SQLalchemy wont execute large DB query
so I was trying to query around 200k rows from a mariaDB using the following code.
with engine.connect() as connection:
    print("test1")
    result = connection.execute(sqlalchemy.text(query))
    dates = [print("test2") for row in result]
    print(len(dates))
engine.dispose()

It works the first time. and then the second time it freeze up after printing test1. Then after interrupt it with ctrl + c, i can run it again . and so on
what is the possible cause, do i handle the connection incorrectly? is there a possible work around?
The database works fine with other system. and this does not happened for smaller query.
i found the following error on syslog:
(I hide some details within <>)
Jul  5 16:52:46 <machine_name> mysqld[1571843]: 2024-07-05 16:52:46 3094934790 [Warning] Aborted connection 3094934790 to db: '<db_name>' user: '<db_user>' host: '<db_host>' (Got an error reading communication packets)


Have you checked for locks?

@snakecharmerb can you specify what locks you meant? the query is only "SELECT" so the DB would not impose locks for that right?

Does this answer your question?

that is unlikely to be the cause, the setting on my.cnf is already several time bigger the the recommended value. other system also don't have any trouble running the exact same query.

Turns out the problem was i did not fetch the result properly a and i did not close the result.
here is how to do it properly
with engine.connect() as connection:
        print("test1")
        result = connection.execute(sqlalchemy.text(query))
        while(True):
            row=result.fetchone() # get one row
            if row is None: # break when there is no row left
                break
            print(row)
        result.close() # close the result 
engine.dispose()


better yet fetchall() method  return all rows and close the result afterwards. so all i need to do was:
with engine.connect() as connection:
        print("test1")
        result = connection.execute(sqlalchemy.text(query)).fetchall()
        for row in result:
            print(row[0])
engine.dispose()

